# MySQL .Net Provider 5.2 does not show up in Data Source dialog of VS 2008 Express

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, visual-studio-express

I have installed MySQL .NET data provider 5.2 (through it's installer) but I could not see the MySQL data provider in Data Source dialog of Database Explorer.

I am using VS 2008 Express edition. Do you have any clues ?

Regards,
Jatan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS 2008 Express (and VS 2005 Express too) doesn't allow you to use MySQL .Net Provider through the Data Source Dialog. The non-Express edition allow you to do the same.

To use MySQL in VS Express, you will have to include a reference to the MySQL DLLs from the location where you installed the Provider (most probably C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net x.x.x).   Or copy the DLLs from the same location to the Bin folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can use MySQL in .NET that way, it is meant as a native .NET library for MySQL,     so you will have to do things code-wise.