# Connecting with remote mysql database, getting the error "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

Tags: c#, mysql, database, mysql-connector

I am making an application that connects to remote mysql database into some cpanel account. I created the database on the cpanel account and defined a username and password for it.  I am using MysqlConnector. So far I have written the following code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
        MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection("SERVER = 64.191.12.54; DATABASE = alyataco_test4application; User ID = xxxxxxxx; PASSWORD = xxxxxxxx");
        c.Open();
```

but i got error :

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

i also saw [Connect to remote MySQL database with Visual C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402355/connect-to-remote-mysql-database-with-visual-c-sharp) but didn`t help too

Comment: try pinging the server or connect via query browser to check if it is a connection error

Comment: Error is : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. , i.e : server is like not found

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your connection string seems wrong. Try:

```
MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection("server=64.191.12.54; database=alyataco_test4application; uid=xxxxxxxx; pwd=xxxxxxxx");
```

See http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql for more connection string exemples.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are your host does not allow remote connections to the database server. Easy way to tell is if you deploy your project to the server and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the solution explorer on your project name. and select "Add Reference" and then from the available files select "MySQL.data" and add it. Now I think it will not give error.